# Magento2 : how to use phtml jquery functions and vars from another phtml jquery script

Tags: magento2, blocks, jquery

I have created a new page containing several blocks :

Simplified Block 1 phtml :

```
<form id="form" class="form " name="form">
    <div class="inputselect">
        <select class="selector" name="yesno" id="input-yesno">
            <option value="yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="no" selected="selected">No</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var DATA;

$("#input-yesno").change(function() {
    doajax();
});

function doAjax() {
    $.ajax({ 
        url : 'foo/index/bar',
        type: "POST",
        data : $("#form").serializeArray(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data)
        {   
            DATA=data;
        },
        error: function ()
        {
        }
    });
}
//]]>
</script>
```

simplified block 2 phtml:

```
<div class="result">
    <p class="viewer" name="viewer" id="viewer"></p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function updateViewer() {
    $("#viewer").html(DATA['message']);
}
//]]>
</script>
```

I would like to be able to call the updateViewer function from doajax() and that updateViewer() access var DATA.

How can I do that?

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 2):

In magento 2 we have use require js to specify we will be using jquery or any third party library in the phtml.

You can just write your js code inside require js block like following ;

```
<script>

require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){

// insert your code here

});

</script>
```

Also if you want to call other functions you can just write all the js  in one js file and include in the layout xml of the required page.